# ADFS 2.0 Installation / Configuration -> Error Page

Tags: configuration, installation, wif, adfs2.0

I've installed ADFS 2.0 on a Windows Server 2008R2, and after installation / configuration wizard I only see the error page when I access "https://myServer/adfs/ls/"

I see a reference number but no entry in the event Viewer. If I create a Wif demo application with the WIF SDK / FedUtil and enter the ADFS Server as existing STS I can find an error in the even Viewer (A token request was received for a relying party identified by the key 'https://localhost/wifdemo1', but the request could not be fulfilled because the key does not identify any known relying party trust).
I've added my demo app in ADFS as RP.

I've used a Self-Signed Certificate for the ADFS installation. I think something with the configuration of my ADFS is not Ok. Can someone please provide me some ideas what may be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Can you see the metadata at

```
https://yourserver/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml?
```

Have you looked at the event log under "Application and Services Logs / AD FS 2.0 / Admin"?

To make sense of the reference number, look here: [ADFS : There was a problem accessing the site - Reference number xxx](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2012/05/adfs-there-was-problem-accessing-site.html)

Double click the RP entry in ADFS and then look in the Identifier tab. That's the URL it expects. Is that how you configured the RP via FedUtil?

Comment: yes I can see the XML File (but I have this IE Warning: There is a problem with this website's security certificate; Might this be a Problem?)

Comment: In the Event Viewer under ADFS 2.0 / Admin I only find an entry when I try to access ADFS from my RP. Not when I open the url myServer/adfs/ls

Comment: The Identifier of my RP is There is "https://localhost/wifdemo1/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml"